# Paramiko get() raises IOError "No such file" if server doesn't support df -hi

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm running into a problem with paramiko where it gives me `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file` when I try to get a file off the remote server.  Here's my code:

```
# set up a transport object t (using an rsa key), which connected successfully
>>> t.is_active()
True
>>> sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
>>> files = sftp.listdir()  # files holds the list ['canceled', 'downloaded', 'FILE.06222012.TXT']
>>> sftp.get(files[2], '.')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

However, when I connect to sftp on the command line (as the same user I opened the python repl with) I *can* get the file.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I found this post which seems like the issue I'm having https://bugs.launchpad.net/paramiko/+bug/492238  In the interactive sftp prompt:

```
sftp> df -hi
Server does not support statvfs@openssh.com extension
```

This bug is from 2009 and wasn't closed out (but I'm using the latest paramiko 1.7.7.1).  Anyone know of a workaround? Can I force paramiko to just do the equivalent of plain sftp get, without trying to check file integrity?

Answer (score 0):

This might end up calling `stat()` at some point anyway, but you could try using  `STFPClient.open()` which returns a `SFTPFile` instance. Then call its `read()` method to get the contents of the file. So, something like this:

```
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
files = sftp.listdir()  # files holds the list ['canceled', 'downloaded', 'FILE.06222012.TXT']
remote_file = sftp.open(files[2])
with open(files[2], 'w') as local_file:
    local_file.write(remote_file.read())
remote_file.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately.  `open()` along with pretty much every method other than `listdir()` triggers the same error

Comment: Where exactly is it failing? Please post the traceback. Are you certain that the failure is in `SFTPClient.stat()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, however, I did not run into problems because of sftp and df. Make sure to give a proper filename for *localpath*!

```
sftp.get(files[2],'file2.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error, "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file",
with my code running on Windows machines but not on macOS computers.
My workaround is to reset sftp._cwd to None and
use the absolute path for the remote file.

Here is an example:

```
sftp = ssh_client.open_sftp()
dir_remote = r"C:\tmp"
file_remote = "hello.txt"
dir_local = r"C:\tmp"
file_local = "hello.txt"
path_remote = os.path.join(dir_remote, file_remote)
path_local = os.path.join(dir_local, file_local)
sftp.chdir(dir_remote)
sftp._cwd = None  # It removes the error.
sftp.get(path_remote, path_local)
assert os.path.isfile(path_local)
```