# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file when using Paramiko in Python to upload file over SSH

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

this question was asked before a few years back by someone but it looks like it went back and forth for some time without a clear answer. That question is here for reference:
[IOError: [Errno 2] No such file - Paramiko put()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481934/ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-paramiko-put)

Basically, I am trying to run a Python script (using Paramiko) in order to upload a file via SSH. I have tried several different things, including changing the URL to my local file so that it's an absolute path rather than relative but I always get a "IOERROR: [Errno2] No such file error regardless of what I do. here is my code:

```
import os
import paramiko

server = "sample_server.net"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", 
"known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username="cb", password="pass")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put("test_upload.xml", "/home/sample/root/cb")
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Has anyone ran into this before or have any clue on what the issue may be? I am absolutely sure that file does exit so I am not sure why it can't be found. Thanks.

Comment: Try using fullpath.

Comment: If you do `os.path.isfile("test_upload.xml")` just before `.put`, do you get `true`?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the file name in the remotepath parameter. From the API docs for put:

*"**remotepath (str)** – the destination path on the SFTP server. Note that the filename should be included. Only specifying a directory may result in an error."*

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient

```
import os
import paramiko

server = "sample_server.net"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username="cb", password="pass")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put("test_upload.xml", "/home/sample/root/cb/test_upload.xml")
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Doing this worked for me.