# Paramiko failing due due to file permissions

Tags: python, centos, sftp, paramiko

I have been trying to automate SFTP transfer from a Windows client via a python script to a CentOS machine running an Apache server. I have created a user account on the CentOS server that can only access SFTP, similar to the instructions listed here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-centos-7

I then used the following code in an attempt to transfer the file

```
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.put(base_dir + '\\report', '/var/www/html/reports/' + host_name, confirm = False)
```

However this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "noschedule_make_report.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "noschedule_make_report.py", line 62, in main
    sftp.chdir('/var/www/html/reports')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 626, in chdir
    if not stat.S_ISDIR(self.stat(path).st_mode):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 460, in stat
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 780, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 832, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 861, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

This code worked when I didn't set the restrictions on the upload user account as described in the Digital Ocean post, and instead had much more liberal permissions and shell login. Is there a way for me to have both the locked out login for the upload user and to use the Paramiko funcitonality?

Please note that using a `sftp.chdir('/var/www/html/reports')` command before the `put` command produced the same error, occurring at the `chdir` line instead.

Also I understand that similar questions have been asked ([IOError: [Errno 2] No such file - Paramiko put()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481934/ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-paramiko-put)), but I am specifically asking if I can relegate these two sets of functionality.

Comment: So can you upload the file to that folder using any (even GUI) SFTP client?

Comment: Do you try to access manually the sftp manually? I pretty sure due to the chroot restriction you set on the SFTP configuration you don't see /var/www/html/reports. What is the value you set to `ChrootDirectory`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can upload files to it by logging into the SFTP command line from bash (sftp user@host)

Comment: Show us exact syntax that you use with `sftp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concept I think you have perhaps overlooked when configuring the sftp part, This is `ChrootDirectory`.

A `Chroot` in Unix world is a way to execute a command or an environment inside a system directory, so this directory appears the root of the system you're into. This is primary used as security feature because there is no way to escape this chroot. For instance imagine you have a path `/opt/server/ftp/users/` and a ftp daemon is `chroot`ed in `/opt/server/ftp/` a client will see the `users` directory when he will do a `ls -al` and it will be impossible to access files on the system like `/etc/`

So this problem has nothing to do with the Paramiko code per-se but with the sftp configuration you set and the comprehension of what is a Chroot environment.

`ChrootDirectory` in you setup define the sftp user will be dropped into this directory when connection it created AND that he'll be impossible to see the full path of the system when it is logged, so when you upload the files you don't have to `chdir /var/www/html/reports` because you can't see this directory. Considering you set `ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/reports`

Check first the `ChrootDirectory` value you set, if you put `/var/sftp/` but you want to access the system path (not the chroot one) `/var/www/html/reports/` this is wrong. Correct to `/var/www/html/reports/` seems legit, then change your code to

```
sftp.put(base_dir + '\\report', '.' + host_name, confirm = False)
```

the character `.` as second parameter means the current directory

Comment: The only thing that was missing from this answer was that I had to create a further subdirectory inside my "reports" folder to upload into. Other than that you were absolutely right. Thanks for your help